# Dojo moveable with a Dojo pausable

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop, scrollbar

I have a div with an attached movable element. Inside the div there is a list of buttons that is accompanied by a scroll bar. When I try to drag the scroll bar it simply drag the whole div around my screen. In this code fragment I am trying to get the moveable to turn off when I click on the scroll bar (which is part of metL).[image]

I have the "metId" which is everywhere else in the div set to resume dragging the div around.

The pause and resume do not work.

Any help resolving the issue would be helpful, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It is quite difficult to answer the question, without seeing the html markup comprising the structure of all relevant elements. There may even be a better approach to do what you are trying to accomplish. Nevertheless, I'm pointing out one possible issue:

The drag and drop action starts, when dojo registers the `dragstart`, `mousedown`, or `selectstart` events on the drag handle. In your case the drag handle is the div with id `"divMenu"+threadId`. All of these events are triggered **before** the `click` event occurs, so pausing the `moveBlocker` has no effect.

In addition I think, your moveBlocker event should not be an empty function. Instead it should actively 'block' the relevant events from being propagated to the drag handle:

```
var moveBlocker = on.pausable(dnd.handle, "mousedown,dragstart,selectstart", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Depending on the behavior you are trying to accomplish, the other event handlers should also be registered on the "mousedown" event.

Comment: THank you for your response however that did not do the trick.